# Is this estimate correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, proof-verification, hilbert-spaces, estimation

If a sequence $\{c_n\}$ of complex numbers is bounded and $\{e_n\}$ is an orthogonal basis of separable Hilbert space $H$ and $x\in H$, then
$$\left\|\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n (x,e_n)e_n\right\|\leq \left\|c_n\right\|_\infty \left \|\sum_{n=1}^\infty(x,e_n)e_n\right\|.$$
It just doesn't "feel right", but I don't want to first use the triangle inequality on the whole sum, because then I can't get the RHS of the inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using orthogonality, we have 
$$\left\lVert \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n (x_n,e_n)e_n\right\rVert^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\lvert  c_n\right\rvert^2   \left\lvert (x_n,e_n)\right\rvert^2      \leqslant \left\lVert \left(c_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}\right\rVert^2  \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \left\lvert (x_n,e_n)\right\rvert^2        $$
and we conclude using again orthognality.